# Why is this statement not compiling correctly?

Tags: math-mode, errors, compiling

For some reason, the following excerpt from my code is not compiling correctly and I can't figure out why.

```
    \begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{100}{-6} &= -16(-6) + 4\\
&\implies z^100 = z^4\\
\\
z^4 &= \left(e^{\frac{-i\pi}{3}\right)^4 \\
&=e^{\frac{-4\pi}{3}} \\
\\
&\cos\left(\frac{-4\pi}{3}\right) = -\frac{1}{2}, ~\sin\left(\frac{-4\pi}{3}\right) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
&\implies z = -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} i \\
\end{split}
  \end{equation}
```

The error I get is that paragraph ended before split was complete and that a missing endgroup has been inserted. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing a closing brace in line `z^4`:

```
...
z^4 &= \left(e^{\frac{-i\pi}{3}}\right)^4 \\ % Closing brace was missing
...
```

Comment: Haha yep that was it. Been stressing out over it for the past 20 minutes. Thank you so much for finding that.